# How to run a query in 50 databases in postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 50 databases. 
All the table schema in all the databases are the same. If I have a new column to be added to one table, I will have to run 50 times to update in all databases. This is very difficult all the time.

Is there an editor for postgres where there is a way to execute a query in all databases?

Currently, I am using dbeaver. I have to change the connection all the time and execute the query. Please help.

Example: I had to alter a table by adding a column.
ALTER TABLE table-name ADD new-column-name column-definition;

It is very difficult to execute for 50 databases.

Comment: You might consider using a [database schema migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) tool such as Flyway or Liquibase.

Comment: One approach is to use scripts to automate the process, such as a bash script or batch file to make each connection in turn and then use `psql` to run the ALTER TABLE script.

Answer (score 2):

For executing this answer, you need to have dblink extension.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
i text;
BEGIN

FOR i in SELECT datname FROM pg_database
LOOP
 EXECUTE 'select * from dblink(''host=localhost
     user=postgres
     password=postgres
     dbname='||i||' port=5432'',''ALTER TABLE table-name ADD new-column-name column-definition'' ) tt(
     updated text)'
END LOOP;
END $$
```

Comment: Should dblink be created already? Please clarify. @Bharti Mohane

Comment: you can create extension dblink in postgres, you can try this.